# Building SAP modules using PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

Anybody aware of SAP module(s) being built using PowerBuilder or any road-map in place for such development in future.

Answer (score 4):

There are some modules built in PowerBuilder. As we become more familiar with our SAP side of the business, we are hopeful to learn about more. We've met with the teams that build these modules and are understanding their roadmap and we've discussed the PowerBuilder roadmap with them as well.

Are you using PB to customize SAP? I'd be interested in discussing more of what prompted your question - please email me! I am out of the office today and tomorrow but will be back next week.

Sue Dunnell
PowerBuilder Product Manager
dunnell@sybase.com

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly you are wanting to call existing BAPI's via PowerBuilder; for example create a Purchase Requisition using the built in BAPI CreaeFromData ?  I have created a couple back in version 8 or 9 of PB and it was quite a challenge it is totally do-able.  I have code for creating Purchase Requisitions and have code which calls a custom "in-house" written BAPI.

I actually thought about building an API for all the SAP BAPI's because of how difficult it was and I can usually find the answer to anything on the web, but not this; had to trial and error it.

Two hints.  Study the BAPI in SAP Object Explorer or maybe it was called BAPI Browser can't remember, but SAP shows the parameters in different order depending on which way you look at them.  To make them work in PB you have to call the parms in the exact order, unlike the Microsoft languages where you can do named arguments and such.  Then you have to be sure to make all REF types REF.  Any ONE item wrong and you get the dreaded system crash which tells you nothing.  If PowerBuilder had not started losing popularity I would have kept writing APIs for various BAPIs

Contact me if you want any sample code.  I can't give any exact code from one of my corporate clients but would be happy to get you going in the right direction.

Sincerely,
R